# MFMailComposeViewController - Can't cancel or go back to previous view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can anyone help me regarding this problem. I can send an email with no problems, but if i try to go back to my previous view it's stuck when i click send or cancel.

I've tried looking on some of the solutions in here but they didnt fix the problem

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



@IBAction func sendMailPressed(_ sender: Any){
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailVC.delegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients(["xxx@mail.com"])
        mailVC.setSubject("image to you!!")
        mailVC.setMessageBody("hello", isHTML: false)

        let image = imageView.image?.ResizeImage(newWidth: 200)
        if let imageD = image?.pngData(){

        let imageData = imageD  as NSData

            mailVC.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "i.png")

        }
        self.present(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    mailVC.delegate = self
```

to

```
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

Everything else will follow naturally. This view controller will also need to *be* a MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: This is covered in the duplicate.

Comment: I was writing my answer before you closed it; didn't know about the duplicate.

Comment: That’s why I pointed it out :)